# linux 6.7 top command defaults to kilo or kibi bytes? How to know

Tags: linux

Linux: Top command says
mem: 263840336k

small k means kibibytes? capital K means Kilobytes. Somehow I am not confused, I thought things in linux were always Kilo/Mega/Giga/bytes,  now I hear about Kibi/Mebi bytes.

So back to oringial question, mem: 263840336k  is kibibytes? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use manpage on your system to get the kind of unit used(To open the manual of `top` use `man top`).
For example on my system:

> 2c. MEMORY Usage
>          This  portion  consists  of  two lines which may express values in
>          kibibytes (KiB) through exbibytes (EiB) depending on  the  scaling
>          factor enforced with the 'E' interactive command.